# New to flutter. Problem in running "Flutter doctor"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator, android-fullscreen

[Screen Shot of Command "Flutter doctor"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHjYO.png)
[Screen Shot of Command "flutter doctor --android-licenses"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05UQQ.png)

Hello Seniors Please help me running this. I think this is the main issue "**proxy server URL extracted from HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment variable could not be parsed.**"

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing same issue please check your ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES. There is Http Proxy in user variable Just (DELETE) it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).